# Scala Slick Escape User Input Strings

Tags: string, scala, escaping, slick

I'm currently developing a service where customers can enter free text in the web interface. To avoid XSS or similar attacks, the text should be escaped in the backend. Does Scala or Slick offer a possibility similar to PHP to escape strings?

So far I checked *StackOverflow* and the *Scala Essential Book* for a working solution, so far with no luck.
Is there a native solution provided by Scala or Slick comparable to PHP's [mysql-escape-string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function [mysqli-escape-string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php) from PHP doesn't help you with doing any sanitization against *XSS*. It was intended to attempt to escape strings, that could cause *SQL Injection*. It is now deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. The preferred way in PHP to prevent your code against *SQL Injection* is to use *Prepared Statement* [with bind variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

That said, neither Slick nor Scala have built-in functions doing string sanitization against *XSS*.

Slick has a [nice feature](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/sql.html?highlight=sql%20injection#string-interpolation), that changes all strings you are inserting using interpolation to bind variables, which prevents *SQL Injection*, but it has nothing to do with preventing *XSS* (it is something similar to *Prepared Statements* but with less boilerplate).

To prevent XSS you should use some library, which allows sanitization of strings, that might potentially contain *XSS*. There's Java project [java-html-sanitizer](https://github.com/OWASP/java-html-sanitizer) from OWASP, that does that. You could use it like:

```
object HtmlSanitizer {

    //First define your policy for allowed elements
    private lazy val policy = new HtmlPolicyBuilder()
       .allowElements("p")
       .allowElements("a")
       .allowUrlProtocols("https")
       .allowAttributes("href").onElements("a")
       .requireRelNofollowOnLinks()
       .toFactory()

    def sanitize(unsafeHTML: String) = policy.sanitize(unsafeHTML)
 }
```

and then:

```
HtmlSanitizer.sanitize("<p><svg/onload=alert('XSS')</p>") // "<p></p>"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. java-html-sanitizer looks good, I'll have a look at that!